# HTML5 Media TimeRanges Object

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-audio

I have just started using the audio elements buffered attribute. I have only tested it in google chrome (canary build). So far the data in the structure has been different from what the default audio interface displays.

I have made two jsfiddles for the two ways I have implemented it

1. The first is the way I would imagine it to work http://jsfiddle.net/VB7Z8/20/
2. The second the way it actually seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/VB7Z8/18/

To see what I mean go to each fiddle (making sure your cache is cleared so it has stuff to buffer) and seek to the right side of the player making sure to leave a gap for it to buffer. I would think that now if you go back to the hole in the middle that the audio would not play but in fact it has been buffered only the buffered object has not been updated.

I have tested it with all the events and I still get the same result. Have I done something wrong or is this a problem with google chrome? I realise this is still in a draft stage of the standard.

Comment: I stole the file from audio.js just as a test file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been changed at some point in the chrome development and it now works as the standard explains